# Shutil find and remove files

Tags: python, file, move, shutil

I am trying to automate some work which is currently done by hand.

The aim is to find all the documents which have, for example, the number 408710 in their file name. Please note that the file name does also include other letters or figures. An example could be `2rsgf54087105f85sfr`. The program should now search for all the files which own the combination 408710 and then move them into the right path.

I do know how to move the files, but so far I am only able to move the files by entering the exact file name. In that case I do only have one file and not all the files with the mentioned combination. Of course I do not know the exact file name in advance anyway.

Here the code for the stuff which is working:

```
import shutil

src = "C:/Users/Startklar/Desktop/Ausgangsordner"
dst = "C:/Users/Startklar/Desktop/Empfangsordner/Sven"
dst2 = "C:/Users/Startklar/Desktop/Empfangsordner/Gerald"

# remove files
shutil.move(src=src + "/AA023300408710LFVI.docx", dst=dst)
shutil.move(src=src + "/BB023310187105ADIK.docx", dst=dst2)
```

Comment: Note: "remove" in English means delete in this context. You probably mean "move".

Comment: `glob.glob(pattern)` will list the files.

Comment: @lllrnr101 glob.glob(pattern) does not work well with non uniform folder structures e.g. base folders with multiple files in different subfolder depths.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the files you can do it like this using regexp:

```
import os
import re
regexp = r'yourPattern.*\.docx$'
res = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if re.search(regexp , f)]
for f in res:
    print('Remove: '+f)
    os.remove(f)
```

You will need to find a regular expression which only finds all the files you would like to remove.

If you want infact move the files, like in your example, this looks like this (just guessing the regexp from your example)

```
import os
import re

src = "C:/Users/Startklar/Desktop/Ausgangsordner"
filters = [["C:/Users/Startklar/Desktop/Empfangsordner/Sven", r'.*LFVI\.docx$'],
           ["C:/Users/Startklar/Desktop/Empfangsordner/Gerald", r'.*ADIK\.docx$']]

for f in os.listdir(src):
    for dst,regexp in filters:
        if re.search(regexp , f):
            shutil.move(src=f, dst=dst)
```